# Php loop for 1 item need to be for 3 items

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin, which let me show questions 1 by one,
but I need it to show question 3 by 3.

```
$questions = $this->test->buildQuestions();
$answered  = $this->answeredQuestions->count();
foreach ($questions as $q => $question) {
  $records = fRecordSet::buildFromArray('WpTesting_Model_Question', array($q => $question));
  $isCurrent = ($answered == $q);
  $this->addStep(new WpTesting_Model_Step('', $records), $isCurrent);
}
return $this->enableStepsCounter();
```

How can I make this code print 3 questions instead of 1?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure your `$questions` array has 3 questions in it?

Comment: sorry i know nothing of php, how could i do it